# Percentage of Outcome

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I have a vendor bill which I need to pay. It is for $800.
The government mandates that before I pay the bill I deduct 2.73% from the **paid** amount of this bill because the vendor is non compliant.

How do I calculate how much to deduct? The rate needs to be calculated on the **paid** amount.

I hope I have explained that clearly. Note, the answer is not $800 x (1-0.0273).

Thanks so much

Comment: So $2.73\%$ is the percentage of the paid amount of the bill, but what is $800$ -  how is it different from the paid amount of the bill?

Comment: If $A$ is the initial bill amount, and $X$ is the amount that is actually paid after all calculations and deductions are done, there are two interpretations I can see.  $A - 0.0273\times A = X$ (*which is the one I would have assumed was the correct one, but you say for whatever reason is not correct*) or $A-0.0273 \times X = X$.  In either case, you can simplify using standard algebraic practices and then plug in the value for $A$ as being $800$ in order to calculate the value for $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is the paid amount, the deduction is $0.0273x$, which is taken off the \$800. So you must have

$$800 = x + 0.0273x = 1.0273x.$$

So

$$x=\frac{800}{1.0273} = 778.74.$$